# Javascript issue with cell.innerHTML()

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I am trying to provide the ability to have a FontAwesome glyph for certain table cells.  This is achieved by using appropriate CSS classes, e.g. `<i  class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x foobar-stat-green"></i>`

Here is the JS I have tried so far :

```
function addRow(tableID,rowData) {
    if (Array.isArray(rowData) && rowData.length>0) {
        var myTab=document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var newRow = myTab.insertRow();
        rowData.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item);
            var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
            // THIS : createTextNode + appendChild = WORKS OK (no "err") !
            //var newText = document.createTextNode(item);
            //newCell.appendChild(newText);
            // SWITCHING TO THIS = WORKS OK (no "err" in console)
            //newCell.innerHTML='';
            // BUT THIS YIELDS "err" in console
            //newCell.innerHTML(item);
        });
    }
}
```

Example input into this function would be :

```
var foobar = ['a','b','c','test+a@example.com','10/10/10 10:10','<i  class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x foobar-status-green"></i>',false];
```

Comment: *"THIS : createTextNode + appendChild = WORKS OK"* and *"SWITCHING TO THIS = WORKS OK"* So...what's the problem? `innerHTML` is a string property, not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerHTML` is not a function, it's a property, you don't use parenthesis with it, write this directly :

```
newCell.innerHTML = item;
```

Without having to first write :

```
newCell.innerHTML = ''; // not needed
```

Answer (score 1):

`newCell.innerHtml` is not a function defined on element. You need to use it as a setter. `newCell.innerHtml = item`.